# ellipsis within class method - unused argument error

Tags: r

I can use the `...` successfully within a normal function. But I've put it in a class method, which in turn is supposed to pass it along to another function call, but this is not happening. What can be wrong?

Code

```
#' @export
overview  <- function(x) {
  UseMethod("overview", x)
} 

overview.query <- function(return.query, ...) {

    SMA.overview  <- ind_add(return.query, ...)
    SMApointer  <- colnames(SMA.overview)[grep("SMA", names(SMA.overview))]
    line.SMApriceDiff  <- ggplot(data = fortify(SMA.overview), aes_string( x = "published", y = SMApointer )) + geom_line() + facet_grid(areaSize ~ . )

}
```

I immediately get the error code when I e.g tried to pass `overview(x, SMAfactor = 100)`

> Error in overview(x.lund, SMA.factor = 100) :    unused argument
>   (SMA.factor = 100)

Comment: Add `...` to the generic and I think `UseMethod("overview")` is sufficient.

Comment: Your `overview()` function should have `...` as well: `overview  <- function(x, ...) `

Comment: A general tip: an excellent way to avoid silly, simple mistakes with things like S3 methods is to grab the source of a well-used R package with an established author and look what they do.